# WSO2 Identity server 5.0 - Pre configured Service provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We would like to ship wso2 IS with our product.Instead of adding service providers manually through console, we want to pre-configure with some default identity providers and  Service providers. I was expecting some xml files by which I can configure these. But seems like there is no such file and previous versions of IS has SCIM rest points to add SP configurations, I don't see them with IS 5.0. Any idea on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is file that you can configure the service providers. You can locate the `sso-idp-config.xml` file in `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/security` directory.  You can find a pre-configured service provider inside this file. It is the Identity Server dashboard (you can access it `https://{hostname}:{port}/dashboard/`).  You can configure multiple service providers using this file.  It is important to note that,  once you configure using this file, configured service providers would be available for all the tenants of the Identity Server. Also,  you can NOT edit these configured service providers from UI.

Comment: Thanks Asela. It worked like a charm. But I don't see the configured service providers from UI.

Comment: Great..!!! Sorry..  i meant, you can not edit from UI that configured from file. I update the comment..

Comment: Do we have same kind of configuration for identity provider as well?

Comment: It would be great if any of you could help with schema or additional attributes (certificate, claims mapping, ..). Any available example? Thank you in advance

Comment: I've checked the source codes and apparently only EntityID and ACS are used from the sso-idp-config.xml file. UseSingleLogout attribute is hardcoded to true and the ACS URL is used

Comment: In the situation of using SAML, how do the files in <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/service-providers fit in?