# WSO2 Identity Server XML config of service providers

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

My company is using WSO2 IS version 5.2.  We have implemented it clustered with 1 manager node and 3 worker nodes. We do not use multiple tenants.  We are implementing a SAML approach to authentication.  Our first implementation was in a development environment which included quite a bit of manual (UI based) configuration. The following was done using the management console:

1. adding custom claims
2. adding service providers (we have 3 currently)
3. assigning custom claims to SPs
4. configure the resident IdP

We now must setup and configure 50 more development, QA and UAT environments.  We would like to be able to do this entirely through XML configuration with no human data entry.  Is there a specific resource that can walk me through the above 4 items?  Note: We have determined how to add our own custom claims through xml config.  So item #1 is no longer an issue but I included it for reference.  I am really mostly interested in items 2,3 and 4.

We did find the following topic in the docs:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files

However, the above link does not go far enough to explain how to map custom claim to SPs.  We also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567606/wso2-identity-server-5-0-pre-configured-service-provider) which asks a very similar question but gives only part of what we are looking for.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Do you want this exactly through files ? If the goal is to automate the process and make it fast, how about creating a client to use the inbuilt admin services?

Comment: I want to avoid manual (GUI) entry of data.  I will look at your suggestion using admin services.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a basic environment and copy the database from the directoy conf/repository/database.